# what is a svn tagged export? How do you use it in your build process?

Tags: svn, build-process, lamp

Specifically I am interested for the LAMP Stack and some of the best practices to use this for various builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'export' and 'tag' are two very different concepts in SVN.  Tags are basically just copies of the project at a particular point in time; as far as the Subversion software knows they are just folders.  'export' on the other hand is an operation supported by the client software, which creates a copy of a directory from the repository without the SVN metadata needed for a working directory.

I'd recommend reading over the [Red Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), especially the sections on [repository layout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.layout) and [tagging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.tags.html).